# Github deploy keys, submodules, ssh

Tags: ssh, github

If I want to access a private github repo with its deploy keys system. Do I need a ssh key-pair for the main git repo and all its submodules or just the parent one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the SSH key-pair for the parent, and for each submodules (if they are private or if you want to make new commits in those submodules).
See for instance "[Pagoda Box](http://help.pagodabox.com/customer/portal/articles/221647)":

> #### Private Submodule Repos
>
> If your submodule is in a private repo you'll need to grant Pagoda Box access to pull from that repo. You can do so by adding Pagoda Box's public SSH Key to the repo.
> If it's a GitHub repo, you can accomplish the same thing by simply adding 'pagodabox' as a collaborator.